# kubebuilder debug web-hooks locally

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, certificate, kubebuilder

We have a kubebuilder controller which is working as expected, now we need to create a webhooks ,

I follow the tutorial
https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/markers/webhook.html
and now I want to run & debug it locally,
however not sure what to do regard the certificate, is there a simple way to create it , any example will be very helpful.

BTW i've installed [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/helm/) and apply the following sample yaml but not sure what to do next ...

I need **the simplest solution** that I be able to run and debug the `webhook`s **locally** as Im doing already with the controller (Before using webhooks),

https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/running.html

Cert-manager

I've created the following inside my cluster

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: example-com
  namespace: test
spec:
  # Secret names are always required.
  secretName: example-com-tls

  # secretTemplate is optional. If set, these annotations and labels will be
  # copied to the Secret named example-com-tls. These labels and annotations will
  # be re-reconciled if the Certificate's secretTemplate changes. secretTemplate
  # is also enforced, so relevant label and annotation changes on the Secret by a
  # third party will be overwriten by cert-manager to match the secretTemplate.
  secretTemplate:
    annotations:
      my-secret-annotation-1: "foo"
      my-secret-annotation-2: "bar"
    labels:
      my-secret-label: foo

  duration: 2160h # 90d
  renewBefore: 360h # 15d
  subject:
    organizations:
      - jetstack
  # The use of the common name field has been deprecated since 2000 and is
  # discouraged from being used.
  commonName: example.com
  isCA: false
  privateKey:
    algorithm: RSA
    encoding: PKCS1
    size: 2048
  usages:
    - server auth
    - client auth
  # At least one of a DNS Name, URI, or IP address is required.
  dnsNames:
    - example.com
    - www.example.com
  uris:
    - spiffe://cluster.local/ns/sandbox/sa/example
  ipAddresses:
    - 192.168.0.5
  # Issuer references are always required.
  issuerRef:
    name: ca-issuer
    # We can reference ClusterIssuers by changing the kind here.
    # The default value is Issuer (i.e. a locally namespaced Issuer)
    kind: Issuer
    # This is optional since cert-manager will default to this value however
    # if you are using an external issuer, change this to that issuer group.
    group: cert-manager.io
```

Still not sure how to sync it with the kubebuilder to work locally

as when I run the operator in debug mode I got the following error:

`setup   problem running manager {"error": "open /var/folders/vh/_418c55133sgjrwr7n0d7bl40000gn/T/k8s-webhook-server/serving-certs/tls.crt: no such file or directory"}`

**What I need is the **simplest way** to run webhooks **locally****

Comment: Refer this [document](https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/running-webhook.html)  may be helpful to you

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu - Thanks,  I tried to follow the doc but still not able to debug it, I get error : `etup   problem running manager {"error": "open /var/folders/vh/_418c55133sgjrwr7n0d7bl40000gn/T/k8s-webhook-server/serving-certs/tls.crt: no such file or directory"}
`

Comment: Refer this [document](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder/issues/1501) [document](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/issues/900) may be it will helpful to resolve your issue

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu - thanks, but there is no provided solution there, am I missing something ? the solution is to remove the webhooks and this works for me before I needed it, now I want to test it locally, any solution will be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me walk you through the process from the start.

1. create webhook like it's said in the cronJob tutorial - `kubebuilder create webhook --group batch --version v1 --kind CronJob --defaulting --programmatic-validation` . This will create webhooks for implementing defaulting logics and validating logics.
2. Implement the logics as instructed - [Implementing defaulting/validating webhooks](https://book.kubebuilder.io/cronjob-tutorial/webhook-implementation.html)

3. Install cert-manager. I find the easiest way to install is via this commmand - `kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.10.1/cert-manager.yaml`
4. Edit the `config/default/kustomization.yaml` file by uncommenting everything that have [WEBHOOK] or [CERTMANAGER] in their comments. Do the same for `config/crd/kustomization.yaml` file also.
5. Build Your Image locally using - `make docker-build IMG=<some-registry>/<project-name>:tag`. Now you dont need to `docker-push` your image to remote repository. If you are using kind cluster, You can directly load your local image to your specified kind cluster:
   `kind load docker-image <your-image-name>:tag --name <your-kind-cluster-name>`
6. Now you can deploy it to your cluster by - `make deploy IMG=<some-registry>/<project-name>:tag`.

You can also run cluster locally using `make run` command. But, that's a little tricky if you have enabled webooks. I would suggest you running your cluster using KIND cluster in this way. Here, you don't need to worry about injecting certificates. cert-manager will do that for you. You can check out the `/config/certmanager` folder to figure out how this is functioning.

Comment: Thanks I try it out and it doesnt works for me I got the same error, any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: did you able to debug it?

Comment: I have faced this same problem before. Check `default/kustomization.yaml` and `crd/kustomization.yaml` for [WEBHOOK] and [CERTMANAGER], You only need to uncomment some lines to get it to work. Also need to have cert-manager installed. That should've fixed your issue. Check this out : [Error /tmp/k8s-webhook-server/serving-certs/tls.crt: no such file or directory" has been faced](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder/issues/1501#issuecomment-1002478317)